# UWP - Customizing ListBoxItemStyle with Stackpanel Content

Tags: xaml, listbox, styles, win-universal-app

I'm struggling with styling concept for a ListBoxItem in UWP-XAML.

What i want to achive is a Style of a ListBox with Items Consisting of a StackPanel of two TextBlocks, which changes e.g. the Foreground of the two TextBlocks DIFFERENTLY when PressedSelected.

With the following ListBox example I can only Style the ContentPresenter in the standard ListBoxItemStyle, and both TextBlocks change together.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DataSet">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="number" Text="{x:Bind Number}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="name" Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the style of the ItemContainer. Replace ContentPresenter with stackpanel and its contents. However I used Binding instead of x:Bind. It seems not possible to use x:Bind inside the style

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ListViewStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>

                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="BorderBackground"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                    Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
                    Opacity="0"
                    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"/>
                            <StackPanel  Background="Transparent"
              Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ContentPresenter" Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ContentPresenter1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>



<ListBox  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" x:Name="listview">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: That worked nicely, thanks for resolving this confusion.